# How can I load external video to YouTube embedded player?

Tags: javascript, youtube, embed

I want to load external video on YouTube embedded player. I tried:

```
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '360',
          width: '640',
          playerVars: {
            'playsinline': 1
          },
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
          }
        });
      }
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        
player.loadVideoByUrl("https://archive.org/download/BigBuckBunny_124/Content/big_buck_bunny_720p_surround.mp4");
      }
```

But it says "An error occurred. Please try again later."
Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: The YouTube player is only documented as supporting YouTube videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i doubt u can play any non-youtube video inside the youtubes iframe-api.